# ошибка OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

в моем приложении при смене картинок через ресурс Drawable растет потребление памяти и она не освобождается, а потом пользователи получают ошибку OutOfMemoryError. Как можно освободить ресурсы от старой картинки Drawable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        if (sb.equals("pic1")) {
        rrr1 = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1, null);
        relativeLayout1.setBackground(rrr1);
    } else if (sb.equals("pic2")) {
        rrr2 = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic2, null);
        relativeLayout1.setBackground(rrr2);
    }
```

Comment: Может где-то ссылки на них остаются? - покажите как Вы с ними работаете. Меняете в одном `ImageView` или список какой-то используйте?

Comment: Лучше покажите свой код. По любому в памяти остаются все открытые изображения.

Comment: Пользуйтесь Picasso/Glide для кэширования картинок

Comment: а по началу я картинки (rrr1, rrr2 и т.д.) грузил сразу все в onCreate(); из-за чего оперативка загружалась сразу до 164 Мб. Сейчас rrr1(rrr2, rrr3...) = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1, null); грузятся только при выборе другой картинки. Оператика освобождается через некоторое время, но если пользователь будет менять быстро то при маленькой своей ОЗУ получит вылет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну правильно - Вы бэкграунд сменили а ссылка (`rrr1`) его держит в памяти. Используйте локальную переменную вместо поля:

```
if (sb.equals("pic1")) {
    Drawable rrr1 = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1, null);
    relativeLayout1.setBackground(rrr1);
} else if (sb.equals("pic2")) {
    Drawable rrr2 = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic2, null);
    relativeLayout1.setBackground(rrr2);
}
```

Такая ссылка будет существовать только внутри блока `if {...}` и по выходу из него `Drawable` будет удерживаться только виджетом. А когда вы смените его на другой он станет доступен для сборщика мусора.